# javascript string replace with all occurence with array value

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, string, replace

I want to replace all occurrences of a string but the issue is that I have an array of remove words & remove words value.

for example :

```
var string = "this is a string to replace. This string should be replaced using javascript";

var replaceArray = ["this","is","string","should","javascript"];

var replaceArrayValue = ["There","are","strings","have to","node.js"];

for (var i = replaceArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

    var finalAns = string.replace(replaceArray[i],replaceArrayValue[i]);
}
```

I am expecting something like

```
There are strings to replace. There strings have to be replaced using node.js
```

I found some solutions in which I got the best solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript). 
but I can't use the string in `/string/g`. I have to use `replaceArray[i]`

Comment: You can. `var regex = new RegExp(replaceArray[i], 'g')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you prefer fixing your approach, you may use a `RegExp` constructor to build dynamic regexps with variables, and make sure  you only match whole words enclosing the pattern with word boundaries. Do not forget to escape the literal patterns, and declare `finalAns` before the loop and initialize with the `string` var contents.

```js
var string = "this is string to replace. this string should replace using javascript";
var replaceArray = ["this","is","string","should","javascript"];
var replaceArrayValue = ["There","are","strings","have to","node.js"];
var finalAns = string;
for (var i = replaceArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    finalAns = finalAns.replace(RegExp("\\b" + replaceArray[i].replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + "\\b", "g"), replaceArrayValue[i]);
}
console.log(finalAns);
```

Note that [Roman's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40461394/3832970) using a single static regex seems to be the most efficient for the current task (no need to build regexps dynamically each time).

Comment: How would you handle if the word to be replaced has a dollar ($) sign.

Comment: @ztalbot Use `replaceArrayValue[i].replace(/\$/g, '$$$$')`

Comment: Wow your fast!.  My original question could not be edited fast enough. 
var string = "$this is string to replace. this string should replace using   javascript";    
var replaceArray = ["$this","is","string","should","javascript"];    
var replaceArrayValue = ["#There","are","strings","have to","node.js"];

Comment: Solution found. My original string was different and all I had to do was a basic   
finalAns = finalAns.replace(replaceArray[i], replaceArrayValue[i]);

Answer (score 4):

Use the following approach with *replacement* function:

```js
var string = "this is string to replace. this string should replace using javascript",
    replaced = string.replace(/\b\w+\b/g, function ($m) {
        var search = ["this","is","string","should","javascript"],
            replacement = ["There","are","strings","have to","node.js"],
            key = search.indexOf($m);

        return (key !== -1)? replacement[key] : $m;
    });

console.log(replaced);
```

From "***High Performance JavaScript***" (by Nicholas Zakas):

> "... regarding out-of-scope variables: store any frequently used
>   out-of-scope variables in local variables, and then access the local
>   variables directly."

Comment: Should be the official answer, works like charm for me with replacing classes in string, all the other answers create problems

Answer (score 1):

**without Regular Exp**

Only can set  **variable**  `string =finalAns;` in loop . Because Every time Loop set old string then issue are occurs ,

```
var string = "this is string to replace. this string should replace using javascript";

var replaceArray = ["this","is","string","should","javascript"];

var replaceArrayValue = ["There","are","strings","have to","node.js"];
alert(replaceArray.length);
for (var i = replaceArray.length - 1 ; i >= 0; i--) {

    var finalAns = string.replace(replaceArray[i],replaceArrayValue[i]);
    string =finalAns;
}
alert(finalAns);
```

**Snippet Exmaple**

```js
var string = "this is string to replace. this string should replace using javascript";

var replaceArray = ["this","is","string","should","javascript"];

var replaceArrayValue = ["There","are","strings","have to","node.js"];

for (var i = replaceArray.length - 1 ; i >= 0; i--) {

    var finalAns = string.replace(replaceArray[i],replaceArrayValue[i]);
    string =finalAns;
}
alert(finalAns);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I arrived to a solution using a declarative approach:

```
const string = 'boo and Boo2'
const dictionary = { boo: 'faa', boo2: 'faa2' }
return string.split(' ')
  .map(word => dictionary[word.toLowerCase()] ?? word)
  .join(' ')
// 'faa and faa2'
```

Answer (score 0):

**format** method is for replacing all occurrences with order of the given array.

**formatAll** method is for replacing all first occurred words with order of the given array (which is asked for in the question)

```
String.prototype.format = function (_key, _data) {
  return this.split(_key).map(function (value, index) { return _data[index] ? value + _data[index] : (value ? value : '') }).join("");
}

String.prototype.formatAll = function (_keys, _data) {
  let shift = () => { _keys.shift(); return _data.shift() }
  return this.split(/\s+/).map(function (value) { return value == _keys[0] ? shift() : value }).join(" ")
}

"path/of/0/object/s/0/feature".format(0, [10,22])
//outputs
'path/of/10/object/s/22/feature'

"this is a string to replace. This string should be replaced using javascript".formatAll(["this","is","string","should","javascript"],["There","are","strings","have to","node.js"])
//outputs
'There are a strings to replace. This string have to be replaced using node.js'

"Merhaba dünya! Merhaba ay!".formatAll(["Merhaba"], ["Hello"])
//outputs
'Hello dünya! Merhaba ay!'

"Merhaba dünya! Merhaba ay!".formatAll(["Merhaba", "Merhaba"], ["Hello", "Selam"])
//outputs
'Hello dünya! Selam ay!'
```